# Remove URLs from image alt text in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

i have a WP installation that lots of image alt text contain the URL of the image. Like:

```
<img alt="https://example.com" src="https://example.com" />
```

This ends up Ahrefs displaying those Alt texts are missing.

I would like to batch edit the alt text to reflect let's say the name of the file or totally remove those alt texts.

I have tried Media Library assistant Plugin but it didn't work out.
I have also run a Better Search and Replace Plugin query but it didn't work either.

Added info: I found an image that in the media library the Alt text appears properly (into-background). I also checked the wp_postmeta table, found the alt text field and it displays the same as the Media Librady (into-background). However when i inspect the image in the browser it gives me the URL inside the Alt text.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress saves alt text inside the wp_postmeta table, just search for one of your media post ID and look for the _wp_attachment_image_alt post meta key.

You will find your alt text there. If you want to simply remove ALL of them you may try with a simple REPLACE made in mysql, watch out with the conditions, if you have no problem in emptying all of them it's easier, if you want to save some, then add a WHERE condition accordingly

Comment: ok got it, i checked what you say. I found an image that in the media library the Alt text appears properly (into-background). I also checked the wp_postmeta table, found the alt text field and it displays the same as the Media Librady (into-background). However when i inspect the image in the browser it gives me the URL inside the Alt text.

Comment: Maybe you have some JS code that is ruining the party for you? Test it disabling Javascript, with chrome you can do it easily with an extension called "Quick Javascript Switcher"

Comment: i deactivated JS, still the same. I also checked some other websites and they do the same...The image looks like it has a proper Alt text, but then when i inspect it the Alt text is replaced by the image URL. Maybe this is how WP deals with images?

Comment: Wait, if you checked some other website and they ALL have that issue then i suggest you to check with another browser or look if you have some browser-extension enable. That really feels like there's something doing bad thing for you. Another thing you can try is to open your page and then right click-> show source code and see what the server is printing. You can do that with your page and any other external websites you've checked

Comment: you are right. I found out that Firefox does this. Chrome is not. Actually Chrome displays no Alt text at all, that complies with what Ahrefs says. thanks so much i think this gets me one step forward.